# I need to show in console.log the complete name (name and surname) of objects using contructor object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 3 objectos in an array.each object has two properties (name and surname). I need to show a console.log with completed name for each object but using a object construtor.

```js
const people = [
        {
            nome:'Raquel',
            sobrenome:'Santos'
        },
        {
            nome:'André',
            sobrenome:'Almeida'
        },
        {
            nome:'Minerva',
            sobrenome:'McGonadall'
        }
    ]

    const Persons = function(name, surname) {
        this.nome = name
        this.sobrenome = surname
    }

    people.forEach(function(item) {
        // I stoped here 
        return item = new Persons            
    })
```

I want to show in console.log the existed objects by using a constructor object

Comment: *I want to show in console.log the existed objects by using a constructor object* - why? Constructors are not really related to printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a function for writing to log.

```js
    const people = [
        {
            nome:'Raquel',
            sobrenome:'Santos'
        },
        {
            nome:'André',
            sobrenome:'Almeida'
        },
        {
            nome:'Minerva',
            sobrenome:'McGonadall'
        }
    ]

    const Persons = function(nome, surname) {
        this.nome = nome
        this.sobrenome = surname
    }
    
    Persons.prototype.log = function() {
      console.log(this.nome + " " + this.sobrenome);
    };

    people.forEach(function(item) {
        let person = new Persons(item.nome, item.sobrenome);
        person.log();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a `class` with a method `getFullName`.

You may have a look, as well, to the different languages of properties and choose only a single one for the whole code.

Your gioven data is converted in the callback for creating an instance of a person.

```js
class Person {
    constructor (name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    
    getFullName () {
        return [this.surname, this.name].join(' ');
    }
}


const
    peoples = [{ nome: 'Raquel', sobrenome: 'Santos' }, { nome: 'André', sobrenome: 'Almeida' }, { nome: 'Minerva', sobrenome: 'McGonadall' }],
    persons = peoples.map(({ nome, sobrenome }) => new Person(nome, sobrenome));

persons.forEach(person => console.log(person.getFullName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

in the foreach:

```
console.log(item.nome+' '+item.sobrenome)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Persons = function(name, surname){
    this.nome = name
    this.sobrenome = surname
    return name + ' ' + surname
}

console.log(new Persons('Raquel', 'Santos'))
```

I'm unsure why you'd need to have to console log via the Object's constructor. Luca C.'s answer is more straight forward.

Comment: This is only an exercise. I am newbie .so I just wanted to see the result of my exercise and  sometimes I dont know how to see the result and where to insert the code

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ES2015 you can also hack your way with [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). Also, providing an own [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) may be a natural choice for this kind of task, see how "Before" and "After" loops are identical.

```js
const people = [
  {
    nome:'Raquel',
    sobrenome:'Santos'
  },
  {
    nome:'André',
    sobrenome:'Almeida'
  },
  {
    nome:'Minerva',
    sobrenome:'McGonadall'
  }
];

console.log("Before:");
people.forEach(function(folk,idx){
  console.log(idx+": "+folk);
});

function Person(){}
Person.prototype.toString=function(){
  return this.nome+" "+this.sobrenome;
};

const proto=new Person();

people.forEach(function(folk){
  Object.setPrototypeOf(folk,proto);
});


console.log("After:");
people.forEach(function(folk,idx){
  console.log(idx+": "+folk);
});

console.log("people[0] instanceof Person: "+(people[0] instanceof Person));
```

(There is a minor cheat with `toString()`: it gets invoked only when an object is converted to string, which is enforced here via prepending the index. A simple `console.log(folk);` would not do the job as JavaScript consoles usually support logging objects, and then they are not stringified.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `console.log({item});` - that will give you all you need in a pretty and named style:
[image]